# Notification, custom layout

Tags: java, android

Вопрос про замену иконок в `custom layout` в `Notification`
`remoteView.setImageViewResource(R.id.button, R.drawable.image);`

Если метод выше вызвать в теле `Notification`, то он сработает и поменяет иконку.
Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на эту кнопку, её иконка заменялась другой иконкой.

Я попробовал тот же метод скормить туда, где происходит обработка этой кнопки (`Broadcast receiver`). Обработка происходит, но иконку не хочет менять.

```
String action = intent.getAction();
if (action.equals(".action.PLAY_PAUSE")) {
    if (MainActivity.mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        MainActivity.mediaPlayer.pause();
        Log.d("broadcast: ", "пауза");
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.pause_play_notif_btn,R.drawable.pause);
    } else {
        MainActivity.mediaPlayer.start();
        Log.d("broadcast: ", "старт");
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.pause_play_notif_btn,R.drawable.play);
    }
}
```

Comment: код обработчика кнопки в студию

Comment: @metalurgus 
`private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        }
    };`

Comment: @DaniilFrolov, добавьте код в вопрос. Именно код, который по-вашему должен менять кнопку.

Comment: Нет, это не код обработчика кнопки.